# Why does calling a JPanel from other class give NullPointerException error?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, getter-setter

I am a newbie at Java GUI,and I'm trying to make my first visual game.A window including two buttons pops up when we run the program,and if you click on one of them,the game starts.At first,I had created a class extending JPanel so my first panel would be created and I would create an object of the class and add it to the JFrame.But I needed to change the panel when the buttons would be clicked,so I created a new JPanel object JPanel in my main game class.
Because the second JPanel was created in a different way,I made my first JPanel into a similar JPanel and put getter and setter to my frame class.But the code gives me NullPointerException error.

Here are my classes:

```html
public class Frame {
 
 //The constructor method for frame.
 
 private static JPanel panel;
 
 public Frame () {
  
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  
  frame.add(panel);    //Adding the panel of the game to the frame.
  frame.setTitle("Halma Game");       //The title of the window popped up when the program runs.
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }

 public static JPanel getPanel() {
  return panel;
 }

 public static void setPanel(JPanel panel) {
  Frame.panel = panel;
 }

}
```

```html
public class MenuPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
 
 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 
 private JButton playButton;
 private JButton recordButton;
    private JLabel label;
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

 public MenuPanel() {
  
  panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(300,400,300,400));
  panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
  panel.setBackground(Color.decode("255128255"));
  
     playButton = new JButton("New Game");
     playButton.setFocusable(false);
     playButton.setBackground(Color.PINK);
     playButton.setFont(new Font("Ariel",Font.ITALIC,25));
  playButton.addActionListener(this); //???     //Mohreha ro ye abstact beheshon bezani khoobe
  panel.add(playButton);
  
  recordButton = new JButton("HighScores");
  recordButton.setFocusable(false);
  recordButton.setBackground(Color.pink);
  playButton.setFont(new Font("Ariel",Font.ITALIC,25));
  panel.add(recordButton);
  label = new JLabel();
  
 }


 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  GamePanel game = new GamePanel();
  game.start();
  
 }
 
  
  
  

}
```

I haven't yet tried the second JPanel on this code,but this one doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi Elena your panel has not been instantiated yet

private static JPanel panel;

when u call

frame.add(panel);    //Adding the panel of the game to the frame.